# Spree - i18n gem issue

Tags: internationalization, rubygems, bundle, spree

I got a problem with a new version of spree gem (branch: '2-3-stable'). When i try to install it, I receive this error.

```
my_store$ rails server
The git source https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git is not yet checked out. Please  run `bundle install` before trying to start your application

my_store$ bundle install
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
 In Gemfile:
  spree (= 2.3.1) ruby depends on
   spree_core (= 2.3.1) ruby depends on
    i18n (= 0.6.9) ruby

 rails (= 4.1.2) ruby depends on
  activesupport (= 4.1.2) ruby depends on
    i18n (0.6.11)
```

But according to `gem list` i got both of this gems installed `i18n (0.6.11, 0.6.9)`. Can someone help me to fix this problem

Comment: Sorry. i figured it out myself simple execution of `bundle update` and then `bundle install` command fixed my issue

Comment: Maybe amend your original post with your finding rather than leaving it buried in a comment?

Comment: Stack Overflow actually encourages you to leave an answer your own question and mark it as correct. It will be easier for future googlers to find than in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, sorry i am quite a noob in all this QA stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Copy from comment section:
```

Sorry. i figured it out myself simple execution of `bundle update` and then `bundle install` command fixed my issue